# R Add Frequency Distribution "Ticks" to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency-distribution

I know this may not be the best example, but I would like to add the distribution of the x-variable (lstat) above the x-axis as shown in the example plot. I provide data for an MWE and the code for a simple line graph.

However, so far I have no clues on how to achieve this. Are there any hints on this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing)

ggplot(data = BostonHousing) +
  geom_line(aes(x = lstat, y = medv))
```

[Example Plot](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/ale.html) for the Frequency ticks above the x-axis:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `geom_segment` function if you want to specify the height of the tick.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing)

ggplot(data = BostonHousing) +
  geom_line(aes(x = lstat, y = medv)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = lstat, xend = lstat, yend = 3, y = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a really nice way of doing it - great answer!

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is called a 'rug plot' and you can implement it using ggplot's `geom_rug()` function, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing)

ggplot(data = BostonHousing) +
  geom_line(aes(x = lstat, y = medv)) +
  geom_rug(aes(x = lstat))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'll also give you a +1 because your answer is definitely correct!